# How to insert dynamic values (numbers) in JS translations file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, translation

I have a translations file in a React application I'm working on (we can't use i18n because of the company policy). Right now the translations look like this:

```
export const translations = {
  foo: {
    en: 'ABC',
    de: 'DEF',
  },
  bar: {
    en: 'GHI',
    de: 'JKL',
  },
  ...
}
```

...and we are using the translations like this:

```
import { translations } from './translations';
...
<p>{translations['foo'][locale]}</p>
```

Now I need to insert numbers in certain translations, e.g. `You have {{number}} new messages`. Is it possible to do this dynamically? Something like this:

```
export const translations = {
  messages: {
    en: 'You have {{number}} new messages',
    de: 'Du hast {{number}} neue Nachrichten',
  },
  ...
}
```

And then in the page to do something like this:

```
<p>{customTranslationFunction(translations['messages'][locale], {number: 2})}</p>
```

**Update:**
I came up with a custom function which looks like this:

```
const translationWithNumber = (numberOfMessages: number) =>
    translations['messages'][locale].replace(
      /\{\{number\}\}/,
      String(numberOfMessages),
    );
```

I'll test it and see if it works.

Comment: It seems like you have all the structure, and just need the function to do the find/replace. What do you have for `customTranslationFunction` so far?

Comment: So far - nothing. I still couldn't come up with anything useful. I was thinking about replacing the string {{number}} with the parameter which is provided to the function...

Comment: @DBS I edited the original post and added a possible solution. I'll test it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic approach would be to pass in the base translation and an object containing all relevant inserted values. You could then apply multiple inserts, and reuse this function for other situations:

```js
const customTranslationFunction = (translation, values) => {
  // If there's nothing to insert, just return the string
  if (!values) { return translation }
  
  // Replace each placeholder with the requested value
  let out = translation;
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(values)) {
    out = out.replace(`{{${key}}}`, value);
  }
  
  // If we're missing a value for a placeholder, throw a warning for the dev
  if (out.match(/\{\{[^\}]*\}\}/gm)) {
    console.warn(`Unexpected translation, no value provided in "${out}"`)
    // You could do various things here, e.g. including a default value
  } 
  
  // return the new string
  return out;
}

const exampleString = '1: {{a}}, 2: {{b}}'

console.log(customTranslationFunction(exampleString, {
  a: "A",
  b: "B"
}))

console.log(customTranslationFunction(exampleString, {
  a: "C",
  b: "D"
}))

console.log(customTranslationFunction(exampleString, {
  b: "123"
}))
```